# Is this test/method known? (testing mean $ = 0$ when all observations have different variances)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

I am sorry, if you can suggest a better title please do ...

Here is the problem. Assume I have variables $X_i$ ($i = 1,\dots,n$) with mean $\mu_i \ge 0$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$. I want to test the null hypothesis $H_0$ : $\mu_1 = \dots = \mu_n = 0$ vs the general alternative "for some $i$, $\mu_i > 0$".

It is natural to consider the statistic
$$ \sum_i X_i$$
but if the $\sigma_i^2$ are unknown, we are in a delicate situation. A possible solution would be to use $\sum X_i^2$ as an estimate of $\sum_i \sigma_i^2$ under the null hypothesis, which leads to the test statistic
$$ {\sum_i X_i \over \sqrt{\sum_i X_i^2}}$$
which should asymptotically be $\mathcal N(0,1)$ under the null hypothesis (assume that the $\sigma_i^2$ are bounded). However under the alternative the variance will be overestimated, and one gets the feeling that this test is not optimal.

Now here is the (strange) idea. Define a log-likelihood-like function
$$ \ell( \theta ) = \sum_i \log( 1 + \theta X_i ). $$
The first derivative (a score-like function) is
$$U(\theta) = \sum_i {X_i \over 1 + \theta X_i} $$
and the opposite of the second derivative (an observed information-like function) is
$$J(\theta) = \sum_i {X_i^2 \over (1 + \theta X_i)^2}. $$

For small $\theta$, $U(\theta) \simeq \sum_i (X_i - \theta X_i^2)$.
Under the null hypothesis, $E( U(\theta) ) \simeq -\theta \sum_i \sigma_i^2$, which is null for $\theta = 0$. We have $E(J(0)) > 0$ so its a maximum. Under the alternative, for small deviations from the null, the maximum likelihood should be around $\theta = { \sum_i \mu_i \over \sum_i \mu_i^2 + \sigma^2 } > 0$.

Finally, $\ell(\theta)$ seems to behave exactly like a brave and honest log-likelihood, the expected maximum of which is $\theta = 0$ under the null, and $\theta > 0$ under the alternative. All proofs based on Taylor developments should still hold for this particular function.
It is important to note that the expected value of $J(0)$ (under the null hypothesis) is $\sum_i \sigma_i^2$ which is the variance of $U(0)$.

So if we treat this function like a real likelihood, and we look on the score test for $\theta = 0$. It is
$$ {\sum_i X_i \over \sqrt{\sum_i X_i^2}},$$
which should be familiar.

Alternatively, a LRT can be used, with a classical trick for getting a one-sided test:
$$ LRT = \text{sign}\left(\hat \theta\right) \sqrt{ 2 \ell\left(\hat\theta\right)- 2 \ell(0) } = \text{sign}\left(\hat \theta\right) \sqrt{ 2 \ell\left(\hat\theta\right)}.$$
Under the null, this statistic  is equivalent to the above written one, but is (on average) higher under the alternative, thus leading to a higher power test (cf numerical experiment below).

Now my question is: is this method known, what's its name? (I am used to endless wheel reinvention ...) Any good reference? Some concrete applications? (the idea to write a log-likelihood like function can certainly be used for other problems ...)

---

Some numerical experiments.

```
N <- 1e2
sigma2 <- rgamma(N, shape = 10, scale = .1) 
          # some moderately dispersed variances

f <- function(mu = 0) {
  X <- rnorm(length(sigma2), mean = mu, sd = sqrt(sigma2));
  L <- function(theta) sum(log(1+theta*X))
  opt <- optim(par=0, L, control=list(fnscale=-1));
  c(theta = opt$par, lrt = sign(opt$par)*sqrt(2*opt$value), 
    score = sum(X)/sqrt(sum(X**2)))
}

# under the null
x <- replicate(1000, f())

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
# distribution of \hat\theta
hist(x[1,])
# comparison of LRT and score
plot( x[2,], x[3,] )
# normal qqplot
car::qqp( x[2,] )
```

[image: H0]

```
# under the alternative
x <- replicate(1000, f(0.7))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
# distribution of \hat\theta
hist(x[1,])
# comparison of LRT and score
plot( x[2,], x[3,] ); abline(0,1, col="red")
```

[image: H1]